# Multiple FOREIGN KEYs between two SQL Server tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I'm creating my near first database for my homework and I have a problem. I have the `Tasks` table which has a column with an employee who is working on this task and an employee who changed a status of the task. So I need to have 2 foreign keys (`EmployeeId` and `ChangedId`) that both reference the `Id` column of the `Employee` table.

Here is the diagram which describes what I want:

[Database diagram. Take a look at the "Tasks" and "Employee" tables.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Soss9.png)

Database was built without problems but I cannot insert items into the `Tasks` table.

Here is my code for this tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employees]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    [FirstName] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [SecondName] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [LastName] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL 
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tasks]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    [Deadline] DATE NOT NULL, 
    [StatusId] INT NOT NULL,
    [ChangedId] INT NOT NULL,
    [StatusDate] DATE NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeId] INT NOT NULL,
    [ShortInfo] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    [ProjectId] INT NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeId) REFERENCES Employees(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (ChangedId) REFERENCES Employees(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (ProjectId) REFERENCES Projects(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (StatusId) REFERENCES Status(id)
)
```

Adding items to `Tasks`:

```
INSERT INTO Tasks(Deadline, StatusID, ChangedId, StatusDate, EmployeeId, ShortInfo, ProjectId)
VALUES ('2019-12-01', 1, 4, '2018-11-29', 2, 'Hack the security system.', 3),
       ('2019-02-17', 4, 1, '2019-01-19', 3, 'Design new class system.', 1),
       ('2019-06-01', 3, 2, '2019-01-11', 4, 'Test the last storyline mission.', 2),
       ('2018-12-05', 2, 2, '2018-10-03', 2, 'Create Zeus statue model.', 2),
       ('2019-05-21', 1, 1, '2019-04-14', 3, 'Test the Horde campaign.', 1);
```

Error info:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Tasks__StatusId__6B24EA82". The conflict occurred in database "Task4", table "dbo.Status", column 'Id'.

Comment: The code is clearly SQL Server.  You should show the insert statement that does not work.  What error do you get?

Comment: Ok, I've made a mistake in my "Status" table. Now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting values into `tasks` should be easy:

```
insert into tasks (deadline, statusid, changeid, statusdate, employeeid, shortinfo, projectid)
    values (@deadlinedate, @statusid, @changeid, @statusdate, @employeeid, 'This is short info', @projectid);
```

You just need to be sure of the following:

- None of the values are `NULL` and they are of the right type.
- All the "id" columns refer to existing rows in the appropriate tables.  For instance, `@statusid` has an integer value, and that value is in `status.id`.

Answer (score 0):

Try naming the foreign keys for employeeid and changedid, as they are referring the same ID column of Employee table.